# How to write GTest for below Adaptor Class(Inherited Class). MockObject for inherited class not working as expected

Tags: c++, googletest

```
class BAdapter : public A, public C
{
public:
    BAdapter(){ 
        auto boundACallback = std::bind(&BAdapter::service_state_A, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        auto boundCCallback = std::bind(&BAdapter::service_state_C, this, std::placeholders::_1);

        A::init_A(boundACallback);
        C::init_C(boundCCallback);
    }
};

//TESTING using GTest Framework

class MockAC : public A, public C
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(init_A, void(TServerStateCallback&));
    MOCK_METHOD1(init_C, void(TServerStateCallback&));
};

TEST_F(BAdapterTest, ConstructorTest) {
    // Set up expectations for the mock object
    TServerStateCallback expectedACallback = [](ESTATE const& state) {};
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockAC, init_A(_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke([&](TServerStateCallback& callback) {
            // Call the callback function with a valid state
            callback(ESTATE::AVAILABLE);
        }));

    TServerStateCallback expectedCCallback = [](ESTATE const& state) {};
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockAC, init_C(_))
        .WillOnce(Invoke([&](TServerStateCallback& callback) {
            // Call the callback function with a valid state
            callback(ESTATE::AVAILABLE);
        }));

    // Create an object of class B
    BAdapter b;

    // Verify that the expectations were met
    Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(mockAC.get());
}
```

It seems that the call to A::init_A and C::init_C inside the constructor of class B is not being intercepted by the mock object (mockAC), despite the expectation being set up correctly. These leading to below Test failure.

Any expert suggestion how to cover such case from GTest framework ?

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mockAC, init_A(_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mockAC, init_C(_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] BAdapterTest.ConstructorTest (0 ms)
```

Comment: `BAdapter` has no any relation to `mockAC`. What is `mockAC`, where is it declared?

Comment: class MockAC : public BAdapter --> Making MockAC inherited by BAdapter also not solving issue

Comment: Of course not, because `MockAC` constructed before `EXPECT_CALL`. You can't make what you want. You can check A and C states after `BAdapter` is created.

Comment: Are init_A, init_C virtual functions? Provide minimal definition of A and C so we could help.

Comment: Yeah sure, Here is class A and class C implementation 
```
class A
{
public:
 A(){}
 virtual void init_A(const TServerStateCallback& callback){
        callback(ESTATE::AVAILABLE);
    }
};

class C
{
public:
 C(){}
 virtual void init_C(const TServerStateCallback& callback){
        callback(ESTATE::AVAILABLE);
    }
};

```

Comment: [edit] the question to add A and C.